# Minimatica theme in wordpress makes the page wider than the content, showing a scrollbar

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using the minimatica theme on a wordpress site I am working on. The theme seems to make the pages wider than the actual page and I can not figure out why. It only happens on the pages so I suspect it has to do with the black title bar, but I haven't been able to figue it out. I have looked at the css and can't see anything wrong. Any help would be greatly apppreciated.

The site is:

http://www.davidhowardpettit.com

Here is the CSS from the theme:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*
Theme Name: Minimatica
Theme URI: http://www.onedesigns.com/wordpress-themes/minimatica
Description: A stylish and modern minimalist theme with a beautiful image gallery slider and an optional blog view. With support for post formats, audio and video playback, ideal for showcasing photography portfolios or podcasting but also great for your everyday blogging.
Version: 1.1.0
Author: One Designs
Author URI: http://www.onedesigns.com/
Tags: white, light, two-columns, fixed-width, custom-background, custom-header, custom-menu, editor-style, featured-images, theme-options, threaded-comments, sticky-post, microformats, post-formats, translation-ready, photoblogging

License: GNU General Public License
License URI: license.txt
*/

/*
    CSS Reset
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/*
    Clear Floated Elements
*/

.clear {
    clear:both;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

.clear:after {
    clear:both;
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    width:0;
    height:0;
}

* html .clear {
    height:1%;
}

/*
    Style HTML Tags
*/

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Vegur';
    src: url('fonts/vegur-light.eot');
    src: url('fonts/vegur-light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/vegur-light.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/vegur-light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Vegur';
    src: url('fonts/vegur-bold.eot');
    src: url('fonts/vegur-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/vegur-bold.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/vegur-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

body {
    background:#FFF;
    color:#000;
    font-family:"Vegur", sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:18px;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
    color:#21759b;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
    color:#d54e21;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-bottom:18px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

h1 {
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:27px;
}

h2 {
    font-size:32px;
    line-height:24px;
}

h3 {
    font-size:27px;
    line-height:20px;
}

h4 {
    font-size:24px;
}

h5 {
    font-size:20px;
}

h6 {
    font-size:18px;
}

p {
    margin-bottom:18px;
}

blockquote {
    color:#444;
    font-style:italic;
    margin:0 30px;
    padding-left:15px;
    border-left:#CCC 1px solid;
}

blockquote cite {
    font-style:normal;
}

blockquote cite:before {
    content:"- ";
}

table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

table th,
table td {
    padding:6px 0;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
}

table th {
    background:#EEE;
    font-weight:bold;
}

dt {
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

dd {
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type:square;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

ul li {
    margin-top:4px;
}

ul ul {
    list-style-type:disc;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

ul ul ul {
    list-style-type:circle;
}

ol {
    list-style-type:decimal;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

ol ol {
    list-style: upper-alpha;
    margin-bottom:0
}

ol ol ol {
    list-style: lower-roman;
}

ol ol ol ol {
    list-style: lower-alpha;
}

address {
    font-size:14px;
    font-style:italic;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

code {
    font-family:Monaco, Consolas, "Lucida Console", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}

abbr,
acronym {
    border-bottom:#999 1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

big {
    font-size:1.3em;
}

cite,
em {
    font-style:italic;
}

pre {
    padding:15px;
    background:#F5F5F5;
    border:#CCC 1px dashed;
    font-family:Monaco, Consolas, "Lucida Console", "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
    margin-bottom:16px;
}

q {
    quotes:inherit;
}

q:before {
    content:open-quote;
}

q:after {
    content:close-quote;
}

strong {
    font-weight:bold;
}

sup,
sub {
    height:0;
    line-height:1;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    position:relative;
    font-size:10px;
}

sup {
    bottom:1ex;
}

sub {
    top:.5ex;
}

#wrapper img {
    max-width:700px;
    height:auto;
}

/*
    WordPress Standard Tags
*/

.aligncenter {
    display:block;
    margin:15px auto;
}

.alignleft {
    float:left;
    margin:0 15px 15px 0;
    margin-left:0;
}

.alignright {
    float:right;
    margin:15px;
    margin-right:0;
}

.wp-caption {
    background:#F9F9F9;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
}

.wp-caption img {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.wp-caption-text {
    color:#333;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.size-thumbnail {
    padding:5px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    margin-right:15px;
}

.gallery-item img {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid !important;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #999;
}

.gallery-caption{
    text-align:center;
}

#content .sticky {
    background:url(images/sticky.png) right top no-repeat;
    border-bottom:#CCC 3px solid !important;
}

.bypostauthor > .comment-body {
    background:#F0F0F0;
}

/*
    Theme Design, Layout and Typography
*/

#header {
    height:100px;
}

#site-title {
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:36px;
    line-height:100px;
    text-transform:none;
width:940px;
}

#site-title a {
    color:#151515;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#slider {
    position:relative;
    background:#151515;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #999;
margin: 0 0 50px 0;
}
.slider2 {
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.nivo-caption {
font-family: "Vegur", sans-serif;
font-size:36px;
line-height:1.5;
}

#ajax-content {
    position:relative;
    max-width:1140px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#nav-slider .nav-previous,
#nav-slider .nav-next {
    position:absolute;
    top:185px;
    right:0;
    width:40px;
}

#nav-slider .nav-next {
    left:0;
    right:auto;
}

#nav-slider .nav-previous a,
#nav-slider .nav-next a {
    display:block;
    width:24px;
    height:40px;
    margin:0 8px;
    background:url(images/next.png) center no-repeat;
}

#nav-slider .nav-next a {
    background:url(images/prev.png) center no-repeat;
}

#slides {
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.kwicks {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-right:#FFF 5px solid;
}

.kwicks .slide {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:230px;
    height:410px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px #000;
    box-shadow:0 0 30px #000;
}

.kwicks .post {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    border:#FFF 5px solid;
}

.opacity {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
    background:#FFF;
    opacity:0.1;
}

.overlay {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
}

.kwicks .post .entry-container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px;
    background:url(images/entry.png);
    display:none;
}

#slider .post,
#slider .post .entry-title a {
    color:#FFF;
}

#slider .post .entry-title {
    font-size:27px;
}

.title-container {
    margin-bottom:30px;
    padding:20px 0;
    background:#151515;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 20px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 20px #999;
}

.page-title,
.single .entry-title,
.page .entry-title {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:48px;
    line-height:48px;
}

#container {
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.home #container {
    padding-top:30px;
    border-top:#CCC 1px solid;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    width:700px;
    margin:0;
    margin-right:20px;
}

.home #content .post,
.archive #content .post,
.search #content .post {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.home #content .post .entry-meta,
.archive #content .post .entry-meta,
.search #content .post .entry-meta {
    margin-bottom:18px;
    font-size:14px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
}

.folded {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    padding:7px 30px;
    margin-left:-15px;
    margin-bottom:0;
    background:#151515;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:16px !important;
    letter-spacing:0 !important;
}

.folded a {
    color:#FFF;
}

.folded:before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:32px;
    left:0;
    border-width:0 15px 15px 0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#fff #999;
}

a.more-link {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:7px 15px;
    background:#151515;
    color:#FFF ;
    text-decoration:none ;
}

a.more-link:hover {
    background:#21759b;
}

.home #content .wp-post-image,
.archive #content .wp-post-image,
.search #content .wp-post-image {
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}

.home #content .entry-title,
.archive #content .entry-title,
.search #content .entry-title {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    line-height:32px;
}

#posts-nav {
    margin-top:-22px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#posts-nav a,
.navigation a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:7px 15px;
    background:#F9F9F9;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.single .entry-header {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.single-format-image .entry-header,
.single-format-gallery .entry-header,
.single-format-audio .entry-header,
.single-format-video .entry-header {
    float:right;
    width:220px;
}

.single .wp-post-image {
    float:right;
    padding:5px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}

.single-format-image .wp-post-image,
.single-format-audio .wp-post-image {
    float:none;
    margin-bottom:25px;
}

.single .entry-meta {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    line-height:36px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.single .entry-meta ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}

.single .entry-meta ul li {
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px dotted;
}

.entry-tags {
    line-height:16px;
}

.entry-tags a {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:1px 15px 1px 5px;
    margin:10px 0;
    background:#CCC url(images/tag.png) right no-repeat;
    color:#000;
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.pagination {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.attachment .entry-content,
.format-image .entry-content {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.entry-attachment {
    margin-bottom:18px;
    text-align:center;
}

.format-audio .entry-attachment {
    text-align:left;
}

.entry-attachment img,
#attachment-nav img {
    float:none !important;
    padding:5px;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #999;
}

.entry-caption {
    text-align:center;
}

.post-gallery {
    margin:auto;
}

.post-gallery .gallery-item {
    float:left;
    margin:10px 0 20px 20px;
    text-align:center;
    width:220px;
}

.post-gallery .gallery-item:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}

.post-gallery img {
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 5px #999;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #999;
}

.post-gallery .gallery-caption {
    margin-left:0;
}

#attachment-nav {
    float:right;
    width:460px;
}

.format-image .entry-comments,
.format-gallery .entry-comments,
.format-audio .entry-comments,
.format-video .entry-comments {
    float:left;
    width:460px;
}

#comments {
    padding-top:20px;
    border-top:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.format-image #comments,
.format-video #comments {
    border-top:none;
    padding-top:0;
}

#comments-title,
#reply-title {
    text-transform:none;
}

#nav-above {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

#nav-below {
    padding-bottom:20px;
}

.nav-previous {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}

.nav-next {
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    text-align:right;
}

ol.commentlist {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

ol.commentlist ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:30px;
}

ol.commentlist li {
    margin:0;
}

.comment-body,
.pingback p,
.trackback p {
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
    background:#F9F9F9;
}
.pingback p,
.trackback p {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.comment-author .avatar {
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background:#FFF;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.comment-author .fn {
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:normal;
}

.comment-meta {
    margin-bottom:10px;
    font-size:12px;
}

.comment-meta a {
    color:#999;
}

.comment-content,
.comment .reply {
    margin-left:86px;
}

.nocomments {
    padding-top:14px;
    border-top:#CCC 1px solid;
}

#respond {
    padding-top:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top:#CCC 1px solid;
}

.format-image #respond,
.format-galelry #respond,
.format-audio #respond,
.format-video #respond {
    padding-top:0;
    border-top:none;
}

#commentform {
    width:460px;
}

#commentform input[type=text] {
    float:right;
    width:370px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border:#DDD 1px solid;
}

#commentform textarea {
    width:450px;
    padding:5px;
    background:#F8F8F8;
    border:#DDD 1px solid;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

#commentform input[type=text]:focus,
#commentform textarea:focus {
    background:#FFF;
}

.required {
    color:#FF0000;
}

#commentform input[type=submit] {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#252525;
    border:none;
    color:#FFF;
}

#commentform input[type=submit]:focus {
    background:#21759b;
}

#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:220px;
    color:#333;
    line-height:36px;
}

.widget {
    margin-bottom:20px;
}

.widget h3 {
    margin-bottom:0;
    color:#000;
    font-size:20px;
}

.widget ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
}

.widget ul ul {
    margin-left:15px;
}

.widget ul li {
    margin:0;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px dotted;
}

.widget ul ul li {
    border-bottom:none;
}

#footer {
    position:relative;
    width:940px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#footer-area {
    margin-bottom:20px;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px solid;
    line-height:36px;
}

#footer-area .widget {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    margin-left:20px;
}

#footer-area .widget:first-child {
    margin-left:0;
}

.widget_calendar table th,
.widget_calendar table td {
    padding:0 6px;
}

#searchform {
    position:relative;
    width:220px;
    height:30px;
    background:#F9F9F9 url(images/search.png) 3px center no-repeat;
    border:#CCC 1px solid;
}

#searchform input[type=text] {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:20px;
    width:185px;
    height:12px;
    background:none;
    padding:9px 5px;
    border:none;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

#searchform input[type=submit] {
    display:none;
}

.nav {
    width:940px;
    height:24px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    font-size:24px;
    line-height:24px;
}

.nav ul {
    position: relative;
    z-index:597;
    float:left;
    top:auto !important;
    bottom:100%;
    list-style:none;
    margin:20px 0;
}

.nav ul li {
    float:left;
    height:34px;
    margin:0;
    margin-right:36px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.nav ul li.hover,
.nav ul li:hover {
    position:relative;
    z-index:599;
    cursor:default;
}

.nav ul ul {
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:-10px;
    z-index:598;
    min-width:150px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background:#FFF;
    border-top:#CCC 1px dotted;
    font-size:18px;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    float:none;
    min-height:34px;
    height:auto !important;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 10px;
    border-bottom:#CCC 1px dotted;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
    bottom:-10px;
    left:99%;
}

.nav ul ul ul {
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility:visible;
}

.nav ul li a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 0;
    color:#252525;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Screenshot of minimatica]

Comment: Add some code here it is useless for another users if the page goes down on the future.

Comment: What have you attempted, so far?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Firefox on Ubuntu - can you give some more details?

It's probably better to ask this at wordpress.stackexchange.com...

Comment: The problem appears on all three major browsers on Windows 8. Firefox, IE, and Chrome. I haven;t tried anything yet as I can;t find anything to try, haha.

Comment: Added a screenshot to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the only way to debug problems like this is to hide everything from the page, one element at a time (using your browsers debugging tools) until the problem goes away.

Start with the basic structural elements under the body tag -- `<div id="#wrapper">` and `<div id="sm2-container">` in your case. Setting `#wrapper` to `display: none` removed the scroll bar, so repeat for each of the elements in that tag.

Using that technique, I narrowed it down to this code in your side bar: `<h3 class="entry-title widget-title">Gallery</h3>`. It has a width of 940px, and is extending outside of the width of the rest of the page.